# What does the tag "-tag:v hvc1" means?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, compression, hevc, ios

I am using FFMpeg to compress a video to X265/HEVC. When I am doing it normally the converted video doesn't working on iPhone or iPad. But while I am using the tag - "-tag:v hvc1" in the command. Now the output video working fine. So what does the tag means? and what's the pros and cons of using this tag?

Lastly, form where I can get these tags and command easily?

Answer (score 3):

The [FFMpeg document](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) gave the idea of using the tag option with a FourCC code, and [H.265/HEVC Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) gave the idea of *Final Cut and Apple stuff compatibility*. The hvc1 is defined to support Apple devices.